# How to create selective patches from an image based on the objects identified

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, conv-neural-network

I have created a numpy matrix  with all elements initialized to zeros as shown:

```
[[[0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]
 ...
```

This is to resemble an image of the screenshot of a webpage which is of the size 1200 X 1000.

I have identified a few rectangular region of interest for different HTML objects such as Radiobutton, Textbox and dropdown within the screenshot image and assigned them fixed values like 1,2 and 3 for the respective object-regions in the numpy matrix created.

So the resultant matrix almost looks like :

```
[[[0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]
  ..., 
 [[1 1 1 1]
  [1 1 1 1]
  [1 1 1 1]
  ..., 
  [0 0 0 0]
  [2 2 2 2]
  [0 0 0 0]
  ...,
```

I wish to now prepare data set for Convolutional neural network with the patches from the screenshot image. For the purpose of improving the quality of the data supplied to the CNN, I wish to filter the patches and provide only the patches to the CNN which has presence of the objects i.e. Textbox, Radiobutton etc which were detected earlier (Radiobutton and dropdown selections should be there fully and button atleast 50% of the region should be included in the patch). Any ideas how it can be realized in python?

Comment: `scipy.misc.imshow()`

Comment: Thank you for the response. I get a 'RuntimeError: Could not execute image viewer.' when trying to use this function. Not sure why.

Comment: How is a 4d array supposed to be an image? An image is 2d, eventually 3d for color images, the 3rd dimension coding RGB. So basically you need to explain how your 4d array is created and how it contains your images. At the moment your question is too unclear.

Answer (score 0):

a very naive approach

```
maxY, maxX = np.shape(theMatrix)

for curY in range(0,maxY):
   for curX in range(0,maxX):
       print theMatrix[curY,curX],
   print " "
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the plot function to plot a 2D-array. Take for example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
x = np.random.rand(3, 2)
```

which will yield us

```
array([[ 0.53255518,  0.04687357],
       [ 0.4600085 ,  0.73059902],
       [ 0.7153942 ,  0.68812506]])
```

If you use the `pyplot.plot(x, 'ro')`, it will plot you the figure given below.

[image: 2d array plot]

The row numbers are put in x-axis and the values are plotted in the y-axis. But from the nature of your problem , I suspect you need the columns numbers to be put in x-axis and the values in y-axis. To do so, you can simply transpose your matrix.

```
pyplot.plot(x.T,'ro')
pyplot.show()
```

which now yields (for the same array) the figure given below.

[image: 2d array transpose plot]

Comment: In my case, I have a 4 dimensional matrix. Will it work in that case?

Comment: No pyplot.plot can not plot a 4D array. It has to be 1D or 2D . Maybe you should update your question a bit because a 1200X1000 sized array will let people understand that your array has 1200 rows and 1000 columns and it is a 2D array. 
Please provide with some extra informations, like a smaller version of your array and the desired output

Comment: Sorry about that. Updated the question.